# Manually writing a function matrixpower() in R

Tags: matrix, r

> **Problem 1 - Matrix powers in R**
>
> R does not have a built-in command for taking matrix powers.
>
> Write a function `matrixpower()` with two arguments mat and k that  will
>   take integer powers k of a matrix mat.

**My attempted solution.**

```
matrixMul <- function(mat1, mat2)
{
    rows <- nrow(mat1)
    cols <- ncol(mat2)

    if(rows == cols)
    {
        matOut <- matrix(nrow = rows, ncol = cols) # empty matrix

        for (i in 1:rows) 
        {
            for(j in 1:cols)
            {
                vec1 <- mat1[i,]
                vec2 <- mat2[,j]

                mult1 <- vec1 * vec2

                matOut[i,j] <- sum(mult1)
            }
        }

        return(matOut)
    }
    else
    {
        return (matrix( rep( 0, len=25), nrow = 5))
    }
}


matrixpower<-function(mat1, k)
{
    pow1 <- abs(k)

    rows <- nrow(mat1)
    cols <- ncol(mat1)

    matOut <- diag(1, rows, cols)

    if(pow1 == 0)
    {
        return(matout)
    }
    if (pow1 == 1)
    {
        matOut <- mat1 
    }

    if(pow1 > 1)
    {
        for (i in 1:pow1) 
        {
            matOut <- matrixMul(matOut, mat1)
        }
    }

    if(k < 0)
    {
        matOut <- solve(matOut)
    }

    return (matOut) 
}

mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol=2)
pow1 <- matrixpower(mat1, -2)
pow1
```

I have a few questions here.

1. Is there any room for improvement in this code?
2. Does this problem ask for manual implementation of multiplication? Or, should the use of `%*%` suffice?

Comment: In case you're more interested in the result than in the exercise of writing the function yourself, check out `matrixcalc::matrix.power()` or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4320/compute-the-power-of-a-matrix-in-r/187477

Comment: I think you can assume that the matrix multiplication operator is allowed in your solution.

Comment: Not the fastest solution (would be what Jorge suggested) but a good candidate for the use of a recursion.

Answer (score 4):

It would be more efficient to use binary exponentiation.

Suppose that you want to raise an n by n matrix to the \$k^{th}\$ power.

The current method requires that you do a normal matrix multiplication \$k-1\$ times.

This of course has complexity \$k\$ multiplied by \$f(n)\$, Where \$f(n)\$ is the complexity of a matrix multiplication ( This is usually \$n^ 3\$ unless you write some fancy shmancy code that no one writes)

If you use binary exponentiation you reduce the number of multiplications to \$log(k)\$. Specifically the number of multiplications is the ceiling of \$log_2(k)\$ plus the number of 1 bits in the binary representation of \$k\$.

This is of course much more efficient for large values of \$k\$.

Comment: Welcome to Code! Can you [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/219059/edit) your answer to give an explanation of why binary exponentiation would be more efficient? If there is documentation that supports this claim then feel free to [cite any such sources](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Done  !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to use math mode !

Comment: yeah - for more info see the [LaTeX section of the formatting page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901360/1201032 for a simple implementation.